# CX_ORACLE TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: python, database, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect a database server from python using cx_oracle . I have constructed connection string as

```
dbconfig['schema']+"/"+dbconfig['password']+"@"+dbconfig["ip"]+"/"+dbconfig['sid']
```

where dbconfig is dictionary with necessary credentials for database connection

I am able to connect to one of the server using VPN connection . But when I try to connect to one of the server in local network it displays "TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor" error.

I even modified tnsnames.ora file with appropriate sid even though it was not required in other case . After that, I was able to login using sqlplus . But had no luck with python code.

Answer (score 4):

You are connecting to the database using a HOSTNAME connection type or what is called "easy connect" - EZCONNECT

Forget tnsnames.ora in your scenario. Not in use when doing a HOSTNAME connection.

You need to get your SERVICE_NAME right. SERVICE_NAME is not the same as SID.

SID is the name of the server-side-processes on a dbnode. Fixed to the dbnode.

SERVICE_NAME is an abtraction. Let's say I am running one database on two dbnodes (RAC) (shared storage), the cluster will expose a service so applications can connect - SERVICE_NAME. The application doesn't have to know anything about the underlying architecture.

```
connection by service_name: user/pass@hostname:port/SERVICE_NAME 
connection by sid user/pass@hostname:port:SID -- NOTE the colon!
```

If you are running Oracle Database 12c you have to specify the SERVICE_NAME, not the SID. Never use the SID! Your application wants a database service!

```
SQL>-- identify the database services (you can have as many as you like)
SQL>-- finance,betting,app1,app2...appN,etc
SQL>-- YES you 'should' run ALL your applications in ONE database (schema separation or pluggable) 
SQL>show parameter service_names

REM try EZCONNECT through sqlplus
REM Note! Add ..(EZCONNECT,TNSNAMES).. to your sqlnet.ora file if not already in. 
C:\>sqlplus user/pass@hostname:PORT/SERVICE_NAME
```

Comment: I already had it solved.Actually, there was problem with SID itself.Created a new one and it worked. Thanks for detailed explanation.